# Libgdx Scene2d Button scaling based on TextureAtlas

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to create a button that will scale when pushed.

```
        textureAtlas = assetManager.get("btn.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        skin = new Skin(textureAtlas);
        btnStyle = new Button.ButtonStyle();
        btnStyle.up = howToBtn_skin.getDrawable("button");
        btnStyle.down = howToBtn_skin.getDrawable("button_pushed");
        myButton = new Button(btnStyle);
        howToBtn.setPosition((Constant.WIDTH / 2) - 41, (Constant.HEIGHT / 2 - 150));
```

[image]

"button" - is the smaller one

"button_pushed" - is the larger one

The button switches image when clicked, but it doesn't scale based on the image size. So when the user click the button, it looks like nothing happened because the size of the button remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Size of the button remains same(normal state and pressed state) and you need some UI interaction touch feel.

Three options. 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> are in similar context.

1. Take two button state image (`button-up`,`button-down`),with same dimension but different tint value. like this -

   [image]
2. If you want same tint value, make image smaller for down state button image but dimension should be same. canvas size for both state should be same and you've to scale down by center.
3. Scale button by yourself when you touch button. You can also add `Action` on your button that will give you better effect. You've to enable transform on your button.

   ```
   button.setTransform(true);
   button.setScale(0.5f);
   ```

Comment: So it's not possible to scale button using textureAtlas images? cause I wan't my button to scale up when it's clicked but return to i'ts original size when released

Comment: go with 2nd or 3rd option, textureAtlas only contains images. there is no concept of scale there.